# Why is CanvasRenderingContext2D.createLinearGradient() not a static function?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I've noticed that [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.createLinearGradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createLinearGradient) is on the prototype of CanvasRenderingContext2D.

This means that one is encouraged to create gradients (along with a few other resources) on the context they are intended to be drawn on.

However, I am able to create a resource on a canvas and use it on another canvas:

```
const ctx1 = document.getElementById('canv1').getContext('2d');
const ctx2 = document.getElementById('canv2').getContext('2d');

const grad = ctx1.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 100, 100);
grad.addColorStop(0, 'white');
grad.addColorStop(1, 'black');

ctx2.fillStyle = grad;
ctx2.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
```

Is there any reason for this other than presumably resource lifetime management behind the scenes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surprising that this question has not been closed as the only answers are subjective, apart from the following paragraph.

Looking through the [WHATWG HTML Living Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#dom-context-2d-createlineargradient) there is no stated reason for the location of createLinearGradient or the other objects created for use only with the `CanvasRenderingContext2D` (2D context) object/interface, apart from the requirement that these methods are a required part of the interface.

The rest of my answer is subjective.

The gradients do not require 2D context nor seem to hold a reference to the canvas or 2D context. Effectively allowing one to completely remove them (canvas & 2D context) ready for disposal by GC. This would suggest there is no resource management in relation to the gradients occurring behind the scenes.

The reason for its location (in my view) would be simply that without the 2D context there is no need for the gradient. One can imagine scenarios where there is a want for style related objects before the any 2D context is created, but there is no case for this to present an insurmountable problem as without context 2D the gradient is unuseable and a proxy object can fulfill intrume requirements.

Though I would have thought that the gradient object created could have been a `SVG.linearGradient` interface as is the case with the `CanvasRenderingContext2D.currentTransform` as a `SVG.matrix` interface. Thus giving the ability to share resources between SVG and 2D context. It would makes sense to do so as they are related.

The standard requires 2D context to support these methods, thus to implement them elsewhere would be redundant.

Comment: Perhaps it allows for per-context caching of resources to be hidden in implementation? Given that WeakMap is now a thing, it could be a relatively easy optimization for browsers to implement. In any case, I'm just going to treat them as simply data structs that I can pass around freely and have GC deal with the cleanup.